# How to disable unlisted file name extensions but make the PHP app work?

Tags: php, iis

I was adviced to untick the "Allow unlisted file name extensions" option in the Request Filtering in IIS. But now the PHP app is not working, I get:

> HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension.

And I am not sure if it's caused because of the `.php` file extension, or the php-cgi.exe module that runs the app.

In either case - what do I need to do to make the PHP work (with php-cgi) and also unable "Allow unlisted file name extensions"?

I think it has something to do with "File Name Extensions" and "Allow File Name Extensions", but not sure how to do it because I tried adding `.php` and that still didn't work

**Edit:** For test purposes I also added `exe` but still error 404.7

**Edit 2:** Added any file type that might be in use in the website: `css`, `js` and still 404.7

**Edit 3:** I just check all the files loaded on the page that I try to load without the request filtering, the added *all* the possible extensions being loaded: `png`, `jpg`, `ttf`, `svg` and more, but still, 404.7

**Update:** Even after adding `.php` extension to the Mime Types as `application/x-httpd-php`, it still doesn't work

Right now I have the following block in `web.config`:

```
                <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false">
                    <add fileExtension=".html" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".ico" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension=".htm" allowed="true" />
                    <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
```

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220155/165358) might help.

Comment: I'm going to try but I'm not there right now. Also, assuming the page being loaded is a `php` file, but it then loads all sorts of files: js, css etc do I need to add them all or just PHP ? Also, in the link it has this part: `PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` where does this token come from?

Comment: You need to add all the extensions you wish to retrieve on the client. You could use just the first method, as you don't need the second one, but for information see [What is the role of public key token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321419/what-is-the-role-of-public-key-token/1322775#1322775)

Comment: By first method, you mean this: `1)Go to IIS -> Click Website/Application -> select "Request Filtering" -> click "Allow file name Extension" -> add ".svc" -> OK`? Because that's what I've been doing so far but still getting 404.7 (that's what I've been doing in my edits 1 2 and 3 in my post)

Comment: So the link may not help. Have you checked that the doing that has added an entry as described in the second method, and if not you could try adding it.

Comment: So by adding the extension via the GUI, I should then see it in the web.config file? Btw, where is this file located? I've never edited it before

Comment: I'd go into the web.config and delete the request filtering block. the web.config will be in the application root (and possibly subdirectories, but the one in the root sets the defaults for the application).

Comment: @B.DLiroy, .svc is specific to the WCF service the linked document was working with. your extensions would be different.

Comment: Oh so if I created the project in an apache environment (xampp) and copied the files to iis, I don't even have this file. So if I create the `web.config` and place it in the project's root, could that fix the issue of why it didn't work even when I added the extensions via the iis gui?

Comment: @FrankThomas, I just checked, IIS actually created `web.config` and it updates it whenever I change settings from the IIS GUI. I just made a test page, an empty PHP page that echoes `Hello, World!`, and in the Network tab in devtools in the browser, I only see the php page and an `.ico` file being loaded. I then added all of the following to the allowed extensions: `php`, `ico`, and just in case also `js` and `css`, but still, it tells me that the extensions are not allowed. Is there a way to check which extensions he is trying to use and fails? Somewhere in logs?

Comment: Update: Even after adding `.php` extension to the Mime Types as `application/x-httpd-php`, it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, the web.config is automatically created if not already present when you change the GUI. The GUI just configures the file, which is read when the app starts.  as for extensions, don't create a mime type for serverside files you want the server to execute. mime types control downloads and how the client handles them. So are you saying you still get this error when you have disabled request filtering, or deleted the whole request filtering block from the web.config and restarted the application?

Comment: Also if you can't disable request filtering, make sure you allow "." as a filetype. this is required for apps that provide extensionless request routing.

Comment: thanks, I just added `.` as well but still, 404. The website works without request filters, but I need to add it, so when I have request filtering it's not working. I have added the block I have in `web.config` to the post at the bottom (I deleted , restarted the app and let IIS create a new one):

Comment: @FrankThomas you are a genius, thank you! After adding `.` I just noticed something different! Even though it's the same 404.7 error, this time, the URL it showed was `example.com/Index.php`, instead of `example.com`, which seem to me to be exactly what you were talking about - the way PHP CGI routes from extension-less URLs to the actual URL. So first, it needed the `.`. Then, it needed the `.php` extension. So I added both `.` and `.php` and it's working! And as you said, no need for mime type for php as it's not on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing request filtering for allowed file types, the setup is pretty intuitive for applications/frameworks that expect request URLs to fully qualify the file extension. However the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis#file-name-extensions) is silent about how to handle extension filtering for apps/frameworks that control application routing using virtual (extension-less) URLs. In those cases the extension is not "" as one might expect, but instead ".".

Adding `<add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />` to the top of the  block will allow the request to enter the processing pipeline so that the application can then process it and route as it sees fit.

```
<fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false">
 <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
 <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="true" />
 <add fileExtension=".html" allowed="true" />
 <add fileExtension=".ico" allowed="true" />
 <add fileExtension=".htm" allowed="true" />
 <add fileExtension=".css" allowed="true" />
 <add fileExtension=".js" allowed="true" />
</fileExtensions>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But then I just tested some different extensions allowed/denied, and noticed that, even if I just leave `.` and `.php`, and remove all the rest, it still works! Do you have any idea why `.css` and `.js` files are still downloaded (as seen in the Network tab in devtool)? Maybe it only refers to files the server is executing and not downloading, i.e. `.php` in this case?

Comment: my first guess is that like MVC, applications PHP uses something like "bundles" to handle the download, and thus the request doesn't make explicit the file type being requested, and the application routing handles it. request filtering doesn't block downloads, it blocks requests to download such that the app doesn't even see the request. if however a request does make it into the pipeline, and is processed by the app, the app can still emit files of any type. if you dig into the requests, are the including the full url with extension to the files?

Comment: I just checked again, my bad, it doesn't work when removing the other file extensions, but it's just saved in the browser cache. So when I clear the browser cache, it doesn't work, then I must add all the extensions (`css`, `js`, etc). thank you